# Bootable one-to-one backup clone of Windows Server 2019?

Tags: windows, backup, backup-restoration, windows-server-2019, windows-server-backup

The ability to make backup clones of an OS link Linux and macOS (eg, [Carbon Copy Cloner](https://bombich.com/), [Super Duper](https://shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html), [ChronoSync](https://www.econtechnologies.com/chronosync/overview.html), etc.) offers wonderful peace of mind.

For years I've struggled with this seeming to not be available for Windows / Windows Server.  Recently I inquired of a few different companies as to whether they offered a product that could facilitate a one-to-one backup of Windows Server so that one could operate two solid state drives with one being a simple continually diff updated clone of the main operating drive such that if something happens to it one could simply boot to the backup drive.

Each company said "No."

Does such a tool exist? If not, what's stopping this from existing?

Options like Acronis True Image are too bulky since they require a boot drive + restore process. This kind of process is insanity for a server situation with time sensitive downtime issues, especially when RAID arrays may not be an option.

One final thought that crosses my mind, but seems sub-optimal: would running Windows Server 2019 on a bootable [Windows To Go](https://www.easyuefi.com/wintousb/faq/en-US/What-is-Windows-To-Go.html) with something like a [USB SanDisk Extreme Pro USB 3.1](https://www.easyuefi.com/wintousb/faq/en-US/What-is-Windows-To-Go-Certified-Drives.html) be a viable option where one would just copy it from time to time and run with such a speedy option?

Comment: I think I know such a tool. It's name `RAID1`. )) Looks like you are trying to facilitate fault tolerance with wrong tech. ) Use shadow copies and system protection snapshots against misconfiguration-related problems, and RAID1 against drive failure.

Comment: Yes, given your description of desired outcome, how would this differ from simple RAID mirroring? The only way I can think of is the ability to store this backup elsewhere but given you want it continually cloned... this won’t give you the usual benefits of backup such as retention, offsite storage etc

Comment: I want it both ways; ie have one onsite and one offsite that's "plug-n-play" - so simply having this solution would ultimately be able to achieve both. Not having equivalent tools is truly remarkable.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this may be the answer to the question when in context of a GPT drive:
https://www.wintips.org/how-to-mirror-boot-hard-drive-on-windows-10-legacy-or-uefi/#case-b

I believe parts 1 & 2 may be able to be circumvented via a drive clone process and then part 3 modified. I'll return and report my findings once I give it a go.